# Unable to provide a Coder for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation using HBaseIO with FlinkRunner

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am running into an issue that "Unable to provide a Coder for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation." using HbaseIO with FlinkRunner.
The Exception is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for ParDo(HBaseProfile)/ParMultiDo(HBaseProfile).output [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().

Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.
  Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
  See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
  Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_core.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:278)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifying(PCollection.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.finishSpecifyingInput(TransformHierarchy.java:190)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:536)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:488)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:370)
    at ac.cn.iie.process.ProfileProcess.process(ProfileProcess.java:91)
    at ac.cn.iie.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:25)
```

I have using maven-shade-plugin to package my jar:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>ac.cn.iie.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.codehaus.plexus.util</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.shaded.plexus.util</shadedPattern>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Does anyone know the reason caused？

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by registering Beam CoderProvider manually. The code is below:

```
CoderRegistry coderRegistry = pipeline.getCoderRegistry();
coderRegistry.registerCoderProvider(
    new HBaseCoderProviderRegistrar().getCoderProviders().get(0));
```

The HBaseCoderProviderRegistrar() provide a CoderProvider list by getCoderProviders() method and the 0 index of list is HBaseMutationCoder.
Because my code use the HBaseIO.write(), just need to register the Mutation Coder.

Comment: Could you share more code please? I have the same issue. And nothing else helps. I dont understand what "to register a coder" means.

Comment: This one helped me so much. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [HBaseCoderProviderRegistrar](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/95f1a5aeba85cd4a6e0eb1ce6eee141e3667d86d/sdks/java/io/hbase/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hbase/HBaseCoderProviderRegistrar.java#L30) already registers the **HBaseMutationCoder** for the **Mutation** type automatically already.

Using the maven-shade plugin without handling **service** files contained in **META-INF/** inside your output jar is a common pitfall for users. You want to add the ServicesResourceTransformer to your transformers list, as so:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

See [Apache documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer) and [ServiceLoader javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for more details. There are many other questions like this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Make the POJO class serializable.
public class CustomerEntity implements Serializable {

```
private String id;

private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer of @K Fred helped. But I Have also discovered that just updating all apache.beam dependencies to the newest version solves the problem too.